# Who provides the shares for exercising a put option?

Tags: options, put-options, option-exercise

I am trying to get into investing and have some questions about options.

1. If I buy a put option (which would be an option to sell stocks as far as I understood), who will provide the stocks to sell if I decide to exercise it? Should I have/provide the stocks or is it the option writer who provides them? And at what price would they be provided?
2. If I choose to sell back the option to the writer, which I understood is called a `buy to close`, is the writer obligated to buy it back? Or can they say no, in which case I would have to wait until expiry?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. One just beginning to invest doesn’t start with options. In fact, most investors who have a successful lifetime towards retirement have never bought an option (or sold one) in their life.

Comment: If you are selling an option to close the position that would be 'sell to close'

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica thanks for the advice. What would they have baught? ETFs? Indexes? Stocks also or never?

Comment: +1 to JTP. Options are highly numerical and require a strong mathematical background just to understand how insanely expensive a ***bet*** they tend to be. You would be better off "investing" your money at a blackjack table in Las Vegas if you don't understand the maths.

Comment: As a beginner it is advised to start out with low-cost funds, ideally being based on a big cross-sectoral index such as the S&P500 or MSCI world. The main reason being that they provide in-built diversification across a large portfolio of shares. This is everything you need for a retirement fund. If you want to go further - just for the fun of it -  start stock picking with well established companies. Compare your own performance to the index funds. The secret to a private investor is investing regularly through a monthly plan, everything else is just a bonus done for fun

Comment: @Can'tTell - yes, to Index ETFs, i.e an ETF that reflects the S&P 500. A beginner can start there, and spend their first few years learning, having invested in just that.

Comment: There are so many people trying to talk you out of options here, I think someone needs to jump in and add some balance. Options are complex, but they are not necessarily risky, in fact many options positions have _less_ downside risk than simply buying stock! The important thing is to understand what you're doing, and since you're here asking questions you're well on your way. Keep at it: more knowledge about financial markets never hurt anyone.

Comment: You are correct in that `Options are complex, but they are not necessarily risky, in fact many options positions have less downside risk than simply buying stock!` However, I'd guess that a large majority of retail traders who utilize options do so in a speculative way, without knowing a lot about what they are doing.  Options are a great tool for mitigating risk.  For trading, especially without option literacy?  Join the money losing cadre.

Comment: @Can'tTell - I'll help by making it simpler. You're going to lose money, lots and lots of money.

Comment: @PhilFrost They are risky. Banks literally set the risk they are selling to you. We call that Vega. If a bank values a risk as being 10 Vega, then sells it to you are 20 Vega, then they have a profit of 10 Vega. How banks realize a 10 Vega Bid/Ask spread into real money is called Delta-Vol hedging. The only long term way to win against this is if you know that the bank is mis-valuing that 10 Vega, and it is actually 30 Vega... And is all this is going right over your head, that is because you don't have a numerate degree with years of experience in this stupid field.

Comment: @Aron It's not going over my head, and how do you know what degree(s) I have? When people say "options are risky!" most people imagine a scenario where [they invest $5000, then "something bad" happens, and now suddenly they owe $730,000](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/alex-kearns-robinhood-trader-suicide-wrongful-death-suit/). My point is for many positions (trivial example: long call) this _can not happen_. But please, sow more FUD by name-dropping greeks, that's surely in the interest of retail investors.

Comment: @PhilFrost My point has always been that you need a handle on the greeks. You can't have that without a mathematical background. Going into Options trading without that, is like playing poker without knowing what the probability for each outcome is, sure, people can win, just not very often. And yes, that is exactly what happen on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/HobbyDrama/comments/ahbad6/options_trading_a_user_in_rwallstreetbets_managed/. $5000 and $57k in the hole...

Comment: @Aron We can agree there, options are complex, and investing in something you don't understand is [never a good idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_selection).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> If I buy a put option (which would be an option to sell stocks as far as I understood), who will provide the stocks to sell if I decide to exercise it? Should I have/provide the stocks or is it the option writer who provides them? And at what price would they be provided?

A put gives the owner the right to sell the stock at the strike price.  If you exercise your long put, you must deliver the shares if you own them.  If you do not own them then if the shares are borrowable, your broker will borrow them from a 3rd party and give them to you for delivery.  This is called shorting.

To short, you will need a margin account, approval for shorting and the necessary margin to support the position (not a good idea for anyone other than an experienced trader). In order to close the short position, you will have to buy the shares to return them to the lender.

If the shares are non borrowable, you'll have to buy the shares immediately in order to deliver them and fulfill your exercise.  Note that it usually makes more sense to sell the put, unless you actually want to go short.

> If I choose to sell back the option to the writer, which I understood is called a buy to close, is the writer obligated to buy it back? Or can they say no, in which case I would have to wait until expiry?

Selling your long put is called sell to close.  Though possible, it would be highly unlikely that your counterparty would be the original writer.

Like stocks, options have market makers who are required to trade at their quoted prices.  Traders can place orders at higher bids and lower asks, becoming the market.  Either way, you will be able to close your position.

Some unsolicited advice?  Read a few option books before you dive into option trading.  You're likely to save yourself a lot of money if you do so.

Comment: More unsolicited advice: Do not ever throw "a lot of money" at an instrument you barely understand or aren't experienced with. Applies to anything, derivatives, cryptocurrencies, leverage, shorts…

Comment: Thanks Bob and @TooTea for the advice. I will probably not spend too much money on options. Just trying to understand the mechanics

Comment: More more unsolicited advice. Don't throw any money at Options without a numerate degree and familiarity with Partial Differential Equations. Also, most options these days aren't settled by delivery. Heck, most options aren't even settled, as that would be a waste of time value...

Comment: You don't need a "numerate degree and familiarity with Partial Differential Equations" to succeed with options.  You need strong arithmetic skills but advanced math is for the quants.  Less than 10% of options are settled, aka exercised with about 70% closed before expiration.

Comment: I'm confused because exercising a put option is not the same as shorting. When you exercise a put option, if you don't have the shares, you buy (not borrow) them on the open market, then force the party who sold you the put option to buy them from you. Then they permanently have those shares (at least until they sell them).

Comment: @stannius Exercising means you sell 100 shares. If you already have 100 or just bought them then it's a normal transaction. But assuming your broker allows, you can always borrow the shares to sell, thereby going short in the process.

Comment: But you can't just "borrow" the shares because once you exercise the put, you won't have those shares any more to un-borrow. Right?

Comment: @stannius - When you exercise one long put, you sell 100 shares and you must deliver them.  If you have them in your account, no problem.  If you do not have them, you must borrow them (you go short) or you must buy them in the open market.

Comment: @BobBaerker You don't need anything to succeed with Options, just like you don't need card counting skills to "suceed" playing Black Jack at Monte Carlo. Don't confuse luck with skill. I am not talking about an Advanced Numerate Degree, which is required for a Quant. I am talking about having enough familiarity for complex abtract concepts to be able to visualize volitility surfaces and why you should never execise an option.

Comment: @Aron - Believe what you want but you don't need to be able to visualize volatility surfaces to succeed with options.  And suggesting that you should never exercise an option is also incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you buy a put at a strike price of $32. Then you're betting that the price will go below $32, and the writer of the option is betting that the price will stay at or above $32. If the price goes to $30, then the writer of the put is down $2. The simplest resolution is for the writer to just buy the put back from you and eat the $2 loss. You can also find someone else to buy the option. Or you can actually buy a share, then use the option to force the writer of the put to buy it for $32. Technically, the writer can refuse a buy to close and force you to have a share to exercise the option. If they do this and you can't get your hands on a share for some reason, then you won't be able to exercise the option.  But generally speaking it's possible to just sell the option either to the writer or someone else (put options are mostly fungible, so a buy to close versus just selling it on the market probably won't be distinguishable from your end).

Comment: `The simplest resolution is for the writer to just buy the put back from you and eat the $2 loss.` It would be more accurate if you accounted for the premium received for writing the put.  Also, you'd buy 100 shares not 'a share'.  Your last sentence is funky as well (buy to close versus just selling it?).